# Custom Duties and Tax on Used Household Goods into Spain

Tags: taxes, customs, imports

Can anyone please provide up to date information regarding the import of (used for over 6 months) household goods into Spain from the UK now we have left the EU?

I'm being told that it's up to 33% of the value on one hand to no tax or duty on the other.

Comment: This will depend on **when** you are importing your personal effects. Within 3 months after taking up residence it should be tax free. A complete inventory, with the items listed also in Spanish, will avoid complications.

Comment: Are you moving to Spain? Do you intend to keep the goods? There is no blanket exemption on tax and duties for used goods as such, only for things you own and take with you as part of a move.